# Get the default language of a BlackBerry device

Tags: java, blackberry

I want to get the language set by the user in the settings screen.  I have checked the DeviceInfo class, but don't see anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the function [`net.rim.device.api.i18n.Locale.getDefaultForSystem()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/3.6api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/Locale.html#getDefaultForSystem()) to return the current locale in use, and to get the human representation of the language for that locale, use [`net.rim.device.api.i18n.Locale.getDisplayLanguage()`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/i18n/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage()).